# jQuery Tablesorter: Sort custom parser via link outside the table

Tags: jquery, parsing, sorting, tablesorter

I apologise for any duplication here, I've already tried running a search on this topic without success. I have a table that I am sorting using jQuery TableSorter, and am using a custom parser to sort 5 of the 9 columns. The custom parser is working well when triggered via the table header text, but I'd like to sort the table columns via a link outside the table.

For those columns that aren't using a custom parser, I have been able to sort them via a link outside the table using the following implementation (see http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-trigger-sort.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("table").tablesorter(); 
$("#trigger-link").click(function() { 
    // set sorting column and direction, this will sort on the first and third column the column index starts at zero 
    var sorting = [[0,0],[2,0]]; 
    // sort on the first column 
    $("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]); 
    // return false to stop default link action 
    return false; 
}); 
});
```

Now I need some way of sorting my columns that use a custom parser via a link outside the table. E.g. I need some way of using the code above to trigger the following code (see http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html):

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method 
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'grades', 
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        // format your data for normalization 
        return s.toLowerCase().replace(/good/,2).replace(/medium/,1).replace(/bad/,0); 
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric' 
}); 

$(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            6: { 
                sorter:'grades' 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

The way tablesorter works is that on initialization, it does through the entire table and saves data from every cell. That data is first processed by the parser and stored in an internal array.

When you sort a column, the original tablesorter actually sorts the internal array, then uses a cross-reference to add the table rows back into the table in the sorted order. This applies even with external links. Tablesorter sorts the internal array and adds the rows back into the table.

The only way to refresh the data within the internal cache is to trigger an "update" which will re-process all table cells, using the parser, to rebuild the internal array.

So... if you want to sort a column that is using a custom parser, do it the exact same as you would on a column without a custom parser. For example, if the custom parser was in the 5th column, make the external link code look like this:

```
$("#trigger-link").click(function() {  
    // apply an ascending sort on the 5th column (zero-based index)
    $("table").trigger("sorton",[ [[4,0]] ]); 
    return false; 
});
```